# Adding two arrays integer values in Flex3

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, casting

I am trying to find the sum of one column's timings which is like '00:00:00' format. I am splitting the time string at ':' and storing into an array. Then trying to add array1[1] value to array2[1] value. Here I'm not getting type casting logic. I'm getting an error when I give `int(array2[1]) += int(array1[1])` .Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should cast your array elements using `parseInt()` before trying to add them. Create a function for that:

```
private function addFromString(a:String, b:String) : Number {
  return parseInt(a,10) + parseInt(b,10);
}
```

You can check whether `a` and `b` are NaN to make it better.

Then just do

`addFromString(ary1[1], ary2[1])`

Comment: Thank you @Robusto. Now, I'm getting proper results. Thanks for detailed explanation with code. :)

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt(string)` converts string to int (returns 0 on failure).